# Keeping one column fixed while th other scrolls

Tags: tailwind-css

I'm playing around with [Tailwind CSS 1.1.2](https://tailwindcss.com/) and wondering how to create a two-column layout where one column is fixed while the other scrolls vertically.

See https://vimeo.com/350933479#t=46s for reference.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The creator of TailwindCSS Adam Wathan made a [Slack clone](https://tailwindcomponents.com/component/slack-clone-1) that does exactly what you're looking for, here's a more basic example and an explanation of why it works:

**Example:**

```
<div class="h-screen flex">
  <!-- Fixed sidebar -->
  <div class="bg-gray-600 w-64">
    <!-- Sidebar content -->
  </div>
  <!-- Scroll wrapper -->
  <div class="flex-1 flex overflow-hidden">
    <!-- Scrollable container -->
    <div class="flex-1 overflow-y-scroll">
      <!-- Your content -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Explanation**
The parent element has the flex and h-screen classes so it fills the height of the screen.

Inside it the fixed column has some width applied or it could be a flex column that shares some portion of the screen.

The scrollable column is wrapped in a div with the classes flex-1 flex and overflow-hidden to make sure it fills the available space but hides overflowed content.

inside the scrollable wrapper have another div which is your scrollable content area with flex-1 so it expands to the available space and overflow-y-scroll to scroll when overflowed. Here's a slightly more styled [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/JHeth/hf6egj97/26/) hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is there a way to add a navbar to the layout without having the 2 scrollbars? https://jsfiddle.net/ybo6L1pd/1/
The navbar should stick to the top https://jsfiddle.net/ybo6L1pd/2/ and, not to show any scrollbar when there is no need (content in the scrollable container doesn't need to be scrolled) https://jsfiddle.net/1ts75wu8/1/

Comment: In your example you have a nav outside of an h-screen content block so it makes the window object have scroll bars. There is some rearranging to do, and you need the main element to have flex-col so the navbar stays above the main content area and sidebar. To make the scrollbar not show inside the nested area when content isn't overflowed you need to change overflow-y-scroll to overflow-y-auto and make sure you move the overflow hidden up to the top of main content area like this (use toggle button to change content length) https://jsfiddle.net/JHeth/d8vj6ncg/19/